# how to get users whose OU includes the keyword: terminated

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-4.0, get-aduser

In Active Directory, I have "Ex Domain Users" folder including a bunch of folders. There are four folders having "Terminated" keyword that I need to retrieve the users from them.

In my powershell script, I do it like below:

```
$users  = Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase “OU=Terminated,OU=Ex Domain Users,DC=xxx,DC=local”; 
$users += Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase “OU=Terminated (ESA),OU=Ex Domain Users,DC=xxx,DC=local”;
$users += Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase “OU=Terminated (Last week),OU=Ex Domain Users,DC=xxx,DC=local”; 
$users += Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase “OU=Terminated (Last month),OU=Ex Domain Users,DC=xxx,DC=local”;
```

I am looking for a way to say `... -Searchbase "OU in ('%Terminated%'), ...")` but I couldn't find the correct syntax or approach for it. Any help would be appreciated.

Regards.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `Get-ADOrganizationalUnit` to enumerate the relevant OUs before calling `Get-ADUser` against each:

```
$targetOUs = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter 'Name -like "*Terminated*"'

$users = $targetOUs |ForEach-Object {
  Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase $_.distinguishedName
}
```

Beware that the `Get-AD*` cmdlets performs a `subtree` query by default, but you can restrict the scope to immediate children of the OU if necessary:

```
Get-ADUser -SearchScope OneLevel ...
```